# tum_ardrone in nvidia-docker: issues with camera feed

Tags: ros, docker, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

after hours of trail and error I managed to build my own docker image with the [tum_ardrone package](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone).

The docker file can be found here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24421105/

Now, when I launch the tum_ardone node, which brings up the:

- "tum_ardone GUI"
- "PTAM Drone Map View"
- "PTAM Drone Camera Feed"

the "tum-ardone GUI" looks just fine and I am able to fly the drone. But the two other "PTAM" windows are broken, because I only see a static "copy" of my background picture.
[image: image description]

I run the following commands in the first terminal

```
docker run -it --net=host  ardrone:nvidia
```

and in the second terminal

```
xhost local:root
nvidia-docker run -it --net=host  --env="DISPLAY"  --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1"   --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw"  ardrone:nvidia
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Kind regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259755/tum_ardrone-in-nvidia-docker:-issues-with-camera-feed/) by [tuxiano](https://answers.ros.org/users/28705/tuxiano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuxiano](https://answers.ros.org/users/28705/tuxiano/) on 2017-04-21**:
Still, can't tell why, but it is related to the "net=host" flag. Because, when I start the container without this flag I'm able to run glxgears and see the gears rotating ... if I start the container with this flag, I only see a black box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In combination with the "--net=host" flag, I had to add the "--priviliged" flag: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/327

```
nvidia-docker run -it --net=host --privileged --env="DISPLAY" --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" ardrone:nvidia
```

---

Originally posted by [tuxiano](https://answers.ros.org/users/28705/tuxiano/) with karma: 26 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0